# Pycharm Can't retrieve image ID from build stream

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Want to connect pycharm docker interpreter. Here is my windows docker status

[image: docker windows]

and here is pycharm status

how can I fix the  issue

[image: pycharm]

Answer (score 7):

in case you follow the step above and didn't work for you try to check if *busybox:latest* image if exists, else pull this again from docker hub.

[Prerequisites﻿ -> the second point](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#prereq)

Comment: It seemed that my PyCharm didn't work with docker due to Internet connection issue. I finially resolved the problem by manually pulling busybox from a docker mirror that my machine could access.

Comment: I also needed to manually pull busybox from my companies mirror.  However I *also* needed to rename the image to strip out my company mirror's name from it before it was recognized by pycharm.  So after the pull I had to run "docker image tag <company_mirror>/docker/busybox busybox"  after that it finally behaved for me.

Answer (score 6):

That error message usually appears when Docker is not able to build your image and tries to run it so it seem that PyCharm can connect to Docker but the build failed.

Try this:

First let's see if PyCharm can connect to Docker (by the error you receive I think it does):

- Open the Services window (Alt + 8)
- Check if you can connect to "Docker" and see all the containers and images you have currently. You may need need to select "Docker" and press the play button on the left.
- If you can't see the "Docker" option, clic on the "+" icon in that window and try to configure a new Docker connection.

[Docker connection in PyCharm - Services window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj4m3.png)

If you can see your images and containers, you're connected to Docker. Let's see if your build fails:

- In the Project window (Alt + 1) right clic on your Dockerfile or Dockercompose.
- We are going to create a Run Configuration. Select the option "Create" that has a Docker icon. If you don't see the option it means you already have one run configuration setup for that file and instead of the "Create" option you'll see an "Edit" option.
- Select "Create" or "Edit" (depending on what options you see) and add the options you need for building and running your Dockerfile or Dockercompose and save the Run Configuration.
- Now you can try and run it from the Run bar at the top right corner (select the new run configuration you just made in the drop down and press play)

Now the Services window will get focused and show the build status. If it fails, you should see the reason there.

Comment: I had the same issue, but my docker-compose doesn't fail. And I have no idea why I got "Can't retrieve image ID from build stream".

Answer (score 0):

What solved this issue for me was making sure I was logged in on Docker for Mac

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command:
docker image prune -a

Comment: it works, thanks!

Comment: ```
% docker image prune -a
WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Images:
untagged: busybox:latest
untagged: busybox@sha256:3fbc632167424a6d997e74f52b878d7cc478225cffac6bc977eedfe51c7f4e79
deleted: sha256:a416a98b71e224a31ee99cff8e16063554498227d2b696152a9c3e0aa65e5824
deleted: sha256:3d24ee258efc3bfe4066a1a9fb83febf6dc0b1548dfe896161533668281c9f4f

Total reclaimed space: 4.262MB

Answer (score -1):

This may also help (following https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#prereq):

- check pycharm settings > Build > Docker > Tools
- The default docker executable was `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe` (windows 10)
- we have to select the file without `.exe` at the end

Answer (score -3):

Maybe installing docker-machine can solve this problem